# Visual C++ - decltype as a return type of a class template's member function

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, visual-studio-2013, decltype

The code

```
template <typename T>
struct Foo
{
    int x_;

    int x() const;
};

int a;

template <typename T>
decltype(a) Foo<T>::x() const
{
    return x_;
}

int main()
{
}
```

produces the following error in Visual Studio 2013:

```
1>...\source.cpp(15): error C2244: 'Foo<T>::x' : unable to match function 
definition to an existing declaration
1>          ...\source.cpp(6) : see declaration of 'Foo<T>::x'
1>          definition
1>          'unknown-type Foo<T>::x(void) const'
1>          existing declarations
1>          'int Foo<T>::x(void) const'
```

but compiles fine on [Coliru's GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2909afae2128292e). Also, it compiles in VS as a non-template class. I guess this is due to Visual Studio's incompleteness and if it is indeed, I'm sure the cause of this already has its name. I just can't find it with my sloppy terminology. What's going on?

Comment: Really MSVC? You can't figure out `decltype(a)` there?

Comment: Doesn't work in VS2015 either. This is fun...

Comment: @Barry I think this may be a consequence of the lack of two-phase lookup, which still applies to VC 14. It probably waits until instantiation time to resolve `decltype(a)`, even though `a` is non-dependent. If we declare `x` in the class definition using `decltype(a)` as well, it compiles. That also explains why it compiles if `Foo` is not a template.