# decltype for a member variable declaration only works in non-template classes?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, decltype, msvc12

I've found some odd behavior. Is it as per the C++ standard, or is it a Microsoft compiler bug? I'm using MSVC 2013 Update 4 (v120 toolset).

This works:

```
#include <deque>

class Test
{
    std::deque<int> _items;
    decltype(_items)::iterator _currentItem;
};

int main()
{
    Test test;

    return 0;
}
```

And this fails to compile:

```
#include <deque>

template <typename T>
class Test
{
    std::deque<int> _items;
    decltype(_items)::iterator _currentItem;
};

int main()
{
    Test<int> test;

    return 0;
}
```

The errors are:

> 1>Source.cpp(7): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier '_currentItem'
>   1>          Source.cpp(8) : see reference to
>   class template instantiation 'Test' being compiled 1>Source.cpp(7):
>   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
>   support default-int

Comment: I suspect the source of the issue is the same as of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31843154/visual-c-decltype-as-a-return-type-of-a-class-templates-member-function).